# Permanency of negative reputation for downvotes on answer

Tags: discussion, reputation

I know from experience that when an answer that I downvoted gets deleted/converted to a comment, that I get the -1 reputation back.
When I read [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) and [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) I think the poster of such an answer gets the -2 back as well.

Is this actually the case? If so would it be better to make all or part of
this reputation loss permanent, to discourage abuse of the "Your Answer" box for comments and other non-answers? And only void the downvotes (and the reputation loss) when the answerer self-deletes the non-answer, to encourage reacting to downvotes and (system inserted) comments that an answer is inappropriate?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works and there's no need to change it. People abusing answers will eventually get caught in an answer ban. Same with questions.

Answer (score 8):

> I think the poster of such an answer gets the -2 back as well.

That is true. Reputation is given back to both users, both the down-voter as the down-voted.

Is this bad?

I don't think so. The point of the reputation isn't to harm someone, it is to indicate the usefulness of the post. It doesn't matter whether it is a question or an answer, or who actually posted it. The user gets some 'appreciation' in the form of reputation and badges for his/her contribution (whether the reputation it gained or lost).

When an answer is deleted, the reputation is given back. The 'harm' to the community is undone and the users walk away without permanent damage. For people abusing the system there are some other things in place, like a post ban.

A user that keeps posting low-quality or abusive stuff will get caught, albeit not (alone) by reputation. He/she will be banned until they have reversed their bad contribution into something positive.